# navigator.network returns 'undefined' in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

When I run the following code that I grabbed off of the Apache Cordova documentation, I get a

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.network.connection')
```

error. I have followed various instructions on installing/uninstalling plugins, but keep getting lost.

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

I have put this in my config files

```
<plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="CDVConnection" />
```

as well as

```
<feature name="NetworkStatus">    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection" />
```

I have tried building in the terminal and from Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add the plugin to your project:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information
```

Also, make sure the plugin is listed:

```
$ cordova plugin ls
```

Comment: I've since moved on and developed on a different framework, so this is now moot.